# Connection could not be created: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction

Tags: java, transactions, wildfly, activemq-classic

We are getting the following exception while getting an `ActiveMQConnection` in our `MDBClient` class:

```
[org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQConnectionFactory:100] (default-threads - 8) Connection could not be created:: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:435)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:67)
  Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000459: Transaction is not active: tx=Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a91021d:6d03d951:608a090d:2d5 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:419)
```

The code for getting connection is below. Error is happening on `connectionFactory.createConnection();` One transaction is successful but all the subsequent transactions are failing with this error.

Our application is running on WildFly 21 and ActiveMQ 5.12.1. ActiveMQ is connected to WildFly through the ActiveMQ JCA Resource Adapter

```java
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = serviceLocator.getConnectionFactory("java:/ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory");
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination destination = serviceLocator.getDestination(conf.getProperty(SystemConfig.OUTPUT_QUEUE_JNDI_NAME));
MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(destination);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when an MDB receives a message the Java EE container automatically starts a transaction which includes the consumption of the message and any other transactional work which the MDB performs (e.g. database updates, sending other JMS messages, etc.). In this way the JMS message is like a unit of work and the consumption of the message along with any other transactional work is performed atomically. If any part of the work fails then every part is rolled-back and, depending on the configuration, the message is either placed back onto the queue (for the MDB to attempt to consume it again) or send to a dead-letter queue or perhaps even discarded.

When you get a connection from a JCA-based connection factory the JCA subsystem tries to automatically enlist that resource into any ongoing transaction. In this case the transaction is not active possibly due to a timeout or some other kind of previous failure. You should look through your logs to see if there were any failures prior to this that would shed any light on why the transaction as been aborted.

The default transaction timeout is 300 seconds (i.e. 5 minutes) so if your transaction lasts longer than this you'll see this kind of error. Long-running transactions are an anti-pattern so you should take measures to avoid them if at all possible. If you absolutely *must* increase the transaction timeout then [this article](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/how-to-increase-the-transaction-timeout-in-jboss-wildfly) has a good explanation of how to do that.

Comment: enabled TRACE logging but couldn't find anything except the above error log. If a transaction takes more than 5mins, then this error is happening.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your question. I hope that helps!

Comment: But not sure where exactly this is happening?
This is what I am doing

1. Reading message from 1st queue using MDB onMessage
2. setting up the database connection for that particular message
3. performing few activities (sometimes it takes 1min and sometimes it takes more than 5mins depending on the data)
4. setting up connection to 2nd queue (failing here)
5. writing the output message to 2nd queue

Comment: how can i increase the transaction timeout? I set connectionTimeout=0 on activemq url

Comment: The `connectionTimeout` on the ActiveMQ URL has *nothing* to do with the transaction timeout on WildFly. I've updated my answer to address your comment.